# How to read a pdf file by using HTML5?

Tags: api, pdf, html

I want to create html file by which i could read any PDF file by providing the source of that PDF file. How can i do this by using only html5?
For example i want read a pdf file which is available in C drive so `scr="http://virdir/mypdf.pdf"`.

I want something like [this](http://test.kenepa.com/testpage.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the developing HTML 5 File API.  Mozilla has a [good explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications), and you can also refer directly to [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/).

Since PDF is a binary format, you will probably want to use [`FileReader.readAsBinaryString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader#readAsBinaryString%28%29).

Parsing and rendering (e.g. to a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/canvas_tutorial)) a PDF in JavaScript *is* possible, but it would be very challenging.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.Have you gone through my test page link. I want something like that.

Comment: @Sandy, as I said, you can render it locally to a canvas in pure HTML 5, but it would be very difficult.  That page is not using either local files or anything new in HTML 5 (that I see).  It's simply serving remote images, probably pre-generated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an open source pdf reader written in javascript.

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

There are APIs available to play with. It comes built into Firefox browser and has good support from Mozilla community.